ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
есть небольшой django-проект, при попытке импортировать из установленного приложения main что-либо  IDE подсказывает, что из файла api/urls.py нет доступа к пакету main, хотя в INSTALLED_APPS я его прописал, при попытке прописать адрес через относительный путь , то есть ..main выдает ошибку ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package, подскажите начинающему, что я не так сделал?


Спасибо, нашел ответ сам, корневой папке проекта необходимо задать Source root

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
